# VSCode - create a column/indentation from text space automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometime i want to create a `good-looking` simple documentation to share with my dev.

Here's a current text documented that i think not good enough:

[image: ugly]

```
Rest API Name  ||  URL
Location || dev/location
Login || dev/login
validateMember || dev/validate-member
-- so on --
```

my expected result is something like this:

[image: nice]

```
Rest API Name   || URL
Location        || dev/location
Login           || dev/login
validateMember  || dev/validate-member
-- so on --
```

does VSCode has automatically what i expected rather than manually indenting?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lmcarreiro.vscode-smart-column-indenter or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=byi8220.indented-block-highlighting or search the market place for `indent`

Comment: @rioV8 `Smart Column Indenter` should be what i looking for, thank you for the suggestion